# How to rid of code duplication when two similar repositories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, java-stream

Upon given type I want to retrieve data from either one or another repority. This is what I came up with:

```
        if (type.equals("first")) {
            codes = firstRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .map(numbers::getCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            codes = secondRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .map(numbers::getCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

Now I am looking for an elegant solution to remove the code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
codes = (type.equals("first") ? firstRepository : secondRepository).findAll().stream()
    .map(numbers::getCode)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```